# Filter a Bitmap to different colors using PorterDuffColorFilter

Tags: android, bitmap, porter-duff, colorfilter

I have the following image:

[image]

Now I’d like to filter this image to different colors at runtime. E.g. I want to be able to generate a **green** version of it, where the lower part is of a darker green, and the top-left part is lighter green.

How can I do this? Is this even possible?

I have tried filtering the bitmap like as follows:

```
private static Bitmap applyColorFilter(Bitmap source, int color) {

    Bitmap empty = Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight());
    Canvas c = new Canvas(empty);
    Paint p = new Paint();

    PorterDuffColorFilter pdcf = new PorterDuffColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
    p.setColorFilter(pcdf);
    c.drawBitmap(empty, 0, 0, p);
    source.recycle();
    return empty;
}
```

I have tried **all** of `PorterDuff.Mode`s, but none of them really works. Sometimes (e.g. SRC_IN) I see the circle totally filled with the new color, without any shading. In other cases I see a square.

I have thought about generating a source image with no color itself, and to render its shading with an alpha channel. However, I’m not sure that would work. I want the resulting image to be fully opaque (apart from the outer shadow you can see above).

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution using `ColorMatrixColorFilter`.

```
// Take values from the destination color
int destA = (color >> 24);
int destR = (color >> 16) & 0xff;
int destG = (color >> 8) & 0xff;
int destB = color & 0xff;

// Give the same weight to source R,G,B, thus grasping the intensity
// -> the shading overlay
float mean = 0.33f;
ColorMatrixColorFilter cm = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(
        new float[]{
                mean,mean,mean,0,destR,
                mean,mean,mean,0,destG,
                mean,mean,mean,0,destB,
                0,0,0,1,destA }
);

Paint p = new Paint();
p.setColorFilter(cm);
...
```

Inevitably, this slightly changes (brightens) the destination color, so I’ll wait some days for a better solution. For my input image, I have better results by lowering the `mean` value to approx. 0.2.

The same result could probably be obtained with a `LightningColorFilter`.